# Sessions in Node.js

Tags: node.js, session-cookies

I'm very new to Node.js and I can't seem to find a way to store sessions, or at least not a official way.

I read you can do it with [Redis](http://redis.io/) I found that express has it's own [Session handler](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession) and I found a [Git repository](https://github.com/josephwegner/node-session).

Now I don't know which method to use... I'm from a PHP background where it was really easy to do this.

I would prefer not to install any more modules. I am currently using [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js), so is there a detailed guide to Express.js' session handler?

Comment: Use `express.cookieSession()`. Check this out:http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: The documentation is a little lacking, is there something more detailed?

Comment: What about this:http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions 
If you Google "node.js express session" you'll get plenty of useful information.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, submit it as a answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to use the proper middleware or include it when you are setting up your Express.js application.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'this is the secret'}));
```

or

```
express --sessions myapp
```

Both the `cookieParser` and `sessions` middleware are required also; the order matters.

After you include the required middleware, a sessions object is added to every request and you can set and get properties on the object.

Setting:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = 'mike';
  res.send('index');
});
```

Getting:

```
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  var user = req.session.user;
  res.send("I know you, you're" + user + '!');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the secret attribute?

Comment: It is an added security layer, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343131/session-secret-what-is-it), it is used to "compute the hash."

Comment: SO if I didn't have a secret would it not work? And whats the point I don't really understand its role, that link says it keeps it protected.

Comment: I read a comment in that link that says the secret is just a salt for the hash, so I assume not required but nice to have!

Comment: It will not work without the secret. express will throw an error.[evidence](http://i.imgur.com/FixNXFE.jpg)